# Change SRID of geometry column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, pgadmin-3

I have in my table column `geom` with geometry, data type of this column is `geometry(Point,102067)`. I want to change `SRID` from `102067` to `5514`, but if I use this command

```
select UpdateGeometrySRID('my_schema', 'table', 'geom', 5514) ;
```

docs say: ERROR:  invalid SRID: 5514 not found in spatial_ref_sys
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('',$1,$2,$3,$4)"

I found, that EPSG:5514 = EPSG:102067 (both is S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North), but in second table I have EPSG:5514, and for example comand `ST_Contains` says: Operation on mixed SRID geometries.

Comment: What is the version of your Postgis ? You probably want to alter the projection ? Did you see ST_Transform ? You can use ST_tranform in you overlap query for example  "... where ST_Overlaps(a.geom,st_tranform(b.geom,5514)).."

Comment: What do you get by running SQL query `select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=5514;`? If result is empty your PostGIS does not support EPSG:5514. That projection is nasty for proj4 (projection library that PostGIS is using), read https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/233.

Comment: result is not empty, i get this: 5514;"EPSG";5514;"PROJCS["S-JTSK / Krovak East North",GEOGCS["S-JTSK",DATUM["System_Jednotne_Trigonometricke_Site_Katastralni",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[589,76,480,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6156"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0 (...)";"+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +alpha=30.28813972222222 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=589,76,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "

Comment: If you did what was suggested in the answer you have added that line to the table and result is no longer empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error happened because EPSG:5514 is no added in spatal_ref_sys table. So you can add it using the following query.

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 5514, 'EPSG', 5514, '+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +alpha=30.28813972222222 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=589,76,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["S-JTSK / Krovak East North",GEOGCS["S-JTSK",DATUM["System_Jednotne_Trigonometricke_Site_Katastralni",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[589,76,480,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6156"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4156"]],PROJECTION["Krovak"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",49.5],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",24.83333333333333],PARAMETER["azimuth",30.28813972222222],PARAMETER["pseudo_standard_parallel_1",78.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5514"]]');
```

Source: https://epsg.io/5514

Click on the side menu under PostGIS to see the insert query.

Check if SRID-5514 is inserted using:

```
SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 5514;
```

Once you have inserted it, you can then change the SRID of your geometry column using the code:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('your_schema', 'table', 'geom', 5514);
```

You can then check the change using:

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for help. :) Please..One more thing.. For one schema I have one spatial_ref_sys? Or one spatial_ref_sys is for all schemas in database?

Comment: You are most welcome. Yes, that is normal. Do you want more spatial_ref_sys tables? Why?

Comment: now in my schema i have two tables: TABLE and SPATIAL_REF_SYS with SRID:5514, but it still says: ERROR:  invalid SRID: 5514 not found in spatial_ref_sys
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('',$1,$2,$3,$4)"

Comment: It is working on my side. Check if you have added srid 5514 using the added query  on the answer, which is `SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 5514;`